# Windows firewall application inbound rules

Tags: windows, firewall

Do I have to have any rules in my inbound and outbound windows firewall app? I think the youngster here applied all these rules to add access...Before I did not use windows firewall app. Had it turned on. I am very good about security. He reset our router twice and had turned on remote in the firewall. I do not leave remote on ever..windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

To restore Windows Firewall default settings, open Control Panel and click open Security applet. Here on the left side, you will see a link Restore defaults. Click on it. You will be taken to a window which will allow yout to restore the default firewall settings.

Comment: Unsolder/clip one of the pins for the reset button on the router. Do not give children admin on your machine. Put children in VLANs. Set up honeypots in virtual machines and connect them to said VLANs. Infect their computers with parental control software. Take the fight to them. Huzzah!